# Array of systemverilog interfaces with different inputs

Tags: arrays, interface, system-verilog

I would like to instantiate an array of systemverilog interfaces where each array element uses a different input.

If all the elements use the same input, then the instantiation is simple:

```
x_if x_IF[`NUM_INTERFACES](clk);
```

Here, if `` `NUM_INTERFACES `` is `2`, then the `clk` input goes to both `x_IF[0]` and `x_IF[1]`.

But if I also have

```
reg clk[`NUM_INTERFACES];
```

how do I instantiate `x_IF` so that `clk[0]` is input to `x_IF[0]` and `clk[1]` is input to `x_IF[1]`?

This is a simple example; I am looking forward to implement this in some sort of loop (probably using `generate`) for an array of 12 interfaces.

Comment: If you implement it using a `generate` loop, you won't have an array, but 12 different instances each in its own scope.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I was wondering how to get this done in a loop. Finally got a solution; I left the interface inputs unconnected in the declaration and later assigned values to them in the generate loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid using `assign` statements, especially with hierarchical references; it makes the code much more difficult to read and maintain.

You could have just done

```
reg clk[`NUM_INTERFACES];
x_if x_IF[`NUM_INTERFACES](clk);
```

A feature with arrays of instances is that if the width of a signal being connected to a port is a multiple of the port width, then each instance sill get a slice of the the signal.

See [LRM 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section **28.3.6 Primitive instance connection list** that applies to module ports as well.

If you use a generate loop instead of an array of instances, then I would do

```
reg  clk[`NUM_INTERFACES];

generate
   for (genvar i=0; i<`NUM_INTERFACES; i++) begin :loop
      x_if x_IF(clk[i]);
   end
endgenerate
```

Comment: Did you mean `x_if x_IF[i](clk[i]);`? Even then, wouldn't that create multiple interface arrays of incremental lengths up to NUM_INTERFACES? Or does it work because of `(clk[i])`?

Comment: No I did not mean that. Each iteration of the `generate` for-loop will create one instance named `loop[i].x_IF` because the begin block named `loop` will get elaborated into loop[0], loop[1], etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was unaware of the ability to reference signals using `loop[i]`.

Comment: Note that you can only reference loop[i] if i is a genvar or constant.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this by assigning the interface inputs from inside the generate loop and leaving them unassigned in the declaration.

```
x_if x_IF[`NUM_INTERFACES]();
reg  clk[`NUM_INTERFACES];

// Code to create clk[`NUM_INTERFACES]

generate
   for (genvar i=0; i<`NUM_INTERFACES; i++) begin
      // Assume that the input port of x_if is called `inp`
      assign x_IF[i].inp = clk[i];
   end
endgenerate
```