# Can I use generate-endgenerate block inside initial in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For e.g.

```
initial
begin

generate
for(genvar i; i < 4; i++)
//Code
endgenerate

end //initial
```

I'm getting error using QuestaSim with the concept. "Near generate: syntax error, unexpected generate "

Comment: What is inside your `generate`, code or module instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** `generate` blocks are evaluated during **elaboration time**. While `initial`,`always` and other procedural blocks start at **zero simulation time**, that is, run-time. Referring to [Systemverilog IEEE 1800-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504837/verilog-generate-genvar-in-an-always-block) :

> Generate schemes are **evaluated during elaboration of the design**.
>   Although generate schemes use syntax that is similar to behavioral
>   statements, it is important to recognize that they **do not execute** at
>   **simulation time**.
>
> They are evaluated at elaboration time, and the
>   **result is determined before simulation begins**. Therefore, all
>   expressions in generate schemes shall be **constant expressions**,
>   **deterministic** at **elaboration time**.

In Verilog, **instantiating** a module means adding **extra hardware** to the board.

This hardware must be added **before simulation starts**(i.e. at compile time). You **can not add/remove hardware** during run time. You can either conditionally **instantiate** a module or **multiply** instantiate it, but never at run time.

Refer [generate block syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770206/syntax-error-near-generate-and-endgenerate-in-verilog/35771504) question for an idea about your error. Also, refer [this question for generate and genvar understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504837/verilog-generate-genvar-in-an-always-block). Referring [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) Chapter 27 for more information.

---

**EDIT**:

To create and pass **multiple interface instances**, the **total number** of interface instances must be governed by some *parameter* or *macro*. You can use this parameter in `for` loop in `generate` block to create **distinct instances** and set each of them using different key as follows:

```
  // Generate multiple instances of interface
  genvar i;
  generate
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_INTERFACES;i++)
    begin
      // Generate clk with different period for each instance
      always #(i+1) clk[i] = ~clk[i];

      inter in(clk[i]);  // Create multiple instances here

    initial
      begin
        // Set each and every instance
        uvm_config_db#(virtual inter)::set(null,"*",$sformatf("in_%0d",i),in);
      end
    end
  endgenerate
```

A complete example is created at [EDAPlayground Multiple Interface](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4f7K) link. Creating multiple instances can be referred from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231264/array-of-systemverilog-interfaces-with-different-inputs).

Comment: Based on number of "Interface" modules generated using "generate", I want to set all "Virtual Interfaces" in uvm_config_db.  But I'm not able to use loops, as to refer each interface instance created by "generate", variables cannot be used."

Comment: I have edited answer for multiple interface instance creation and passing using `uvm_config_db`. Kindly refer the given link for example code.